# Adobe Air Desktop App hanging-up (not responding)

Tags: multithreading, apache-flex, sockets, networking, air

i am doing networking in my app.. the data sent by the PCs (with the app installed) are about 3KB simultaneously (real-time computations are done in my app).. i was wondering why did my app is not responding when sending the data to different PCs? most platform affected are Ubuntu 12.04 (precise pangolin)

2nd question : how can i achieve multithreading in adobe air desktop apps?

sorry for my english...

Comment: without codes, we can't help. post related codes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 2nd question, to have multi-threading in Adobe AIR Desktop Apps, you will require Flash Player 11.4 and AIR 3.4. There is a new concurrency API with [Worker](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html) class.

Post codes for 1st question before we can help.

Comment: sad to say, linux is not supported anymore (stopped at air 2.6), is there any other way?

Comment: No. Consider using another programming language / framework instead, such as Qt / Java .

Comment: Or perhaps try utilising native processes to do the heavy work.